# Problem converting 'even though' clause to 'despite' clause: 'Despite losing...'

Tags: clauses, subordinate-clauses, dependent-clause

I stumbled across this question in 'Intermediate Language Practice' by Michael Vince: 
'Even though they were losing at half-time, City won in the end.
Despite________________________________'

The answer given is 'Despite losing at half-time, City won in the end.'

For me, the answer doesn't work. Something like 'Despite being behind at half-time...' would be better.

However, I am having trouble explaining *why* it doesn't work. Is it because the tenses for 'lose' and 'win' do not agree in the original 'even though' sentence so there is ambiguity when you try and reduce 'were losing' to 'losing' because the 'won in the end' makes us read the subordinate clause as 'they lost'?

Comment: Yes, I think your proposed explanation fits the bill nicely.

Comment: I think it works, but maybe it could be improved thus: "Despite their losing at half-time..." The team lost the first half of the match, but won in the second half. Makes sense to me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: No. *they* ***were*** *losing at halftime* is not the same as *losing at halftime*.  *Despite losing at halftime* really means *despite having lost at halftime*, which makes no sense (if the game resumes past halftime). *Despite losing* means *in spite of losing*, which implies that the subject has already lost.

Comment: @drew I know football/soccer commentators are not the greatest source of grammatical or semantical correctness, but I have heard of teams who "lost the first half" to then make a comeback in the second half and win a game. If for example an incident (e.g. heavy rain) occurs during the break and a match has to be abandoned, bookies still have to pay to pundits who had bet *only* on the first-half result.  In the UK people will bet on anything and that example is very typical.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Yes, one hears that. But it is really a figurative expression, comparing the first half to a game. If there first half were the whole game then they would have lost: they effectively *lost the first half*. And *losing the first half* is not the same as *losing [the game] at halftime*.

Comment: I have a different view here.  //Despite losing at half-time, City won in the end.// Can 'despite' replace 'even though' here?  It's because the sentences when converted are quite fine even without 'despite'. E.g., Losing at half-time, City won in the end; Having lost at half-time, City won in the end.  Why should we use 'despite'? It makes sense if we write, Despite the loss at half-time, City won in the end.  Others' views?

Comment: @drew and Mari-LouA Thank you both for a worthwhile exchange.  The problem, as I'm sure you both noticed, is the usual 'right/wrong' nature of ELL test examples.  The "correct" answer is ambiguous rather than wrong.  'Though' is a subordinating conjunction, requiring a tensed verb.  'Despite' modifies a noun phrase (with, strictly speaking, no tense).  So it makes us uncomfortable, even though there is nothing strictly wrong with it. The other way round is less of a problem:  "They won in the end, despite losing at half time."  Or is it?  I prefer "despite being behind" as less troublesome.

Answer (score 2):

The ambiguity arises in OP's rephrasing because in *his* version, *[despite] **losing*** could also mean ***having lost*** (a "completed", not a "continuous" action). The easiest way to avoid this is...

> *Despite **having been** losing at half-time, City won in the end.*

The reason we don't normally use the above form is more fully explored by [this answer on English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/15380/126) - basically, it's the *horror aequi* principle: we don't like multiple occurrences of the same linguistic element (in this case, two ***-ing*** forms) in close proximity, particularly when they're performing different syntactic roles. But in this case we must do it, to avoid ambiguity.

Note that in principle it could be changed to *Despite **being losing** at half-time*, but that really would be [“The horror! The horror!”](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/55872-the-horror-the-horror) (originally Proust, but better known to many as Kurtz's final words in [Apocalypse Now](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078788/)).

Comment: *O horror aequi!*

Comment: @StoneyB: Good catch. I'd rather have seen this question on ELL in the first place, but it's certainly worth linking to [your answer there](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15378/)

Comment: Your answer is correct, including your proposal to avoid the problem.  However, the OP's solution is more natural (and even clearer): *despite* ***being behind*** *at half-time*.

Comment: @Drew: I think you miss the whole point of the question. Neither OP nor me are interested in *despite being behind* (so it's not a "solution"). The question is about how the specific verb **to lose** works here, particularly focussing on the fact that *to be losing* is a "continuous state" that may be an intermediate stage in a process culminating in the "completed action" of *winning* (or *losing*, obviously). Though I might have mentioned that alternative ***if*** OP hadn't already, ***and if*** the question had been asked on ELL rather than ELU.

Comment: I don't think I miss *the whole point* of the question. And I disagree that *despite losing at halftime* is even ambiguous in this context. It can only mean *despite having lost at halftime*, IMO.  *Although losing at halftime* could express continuing action, as being short for, say, *although they were losing at halftime*; *despite* cannot, IMO. It would be a stretch to say it was short for *despite the fact that they were losing at halftime*, when the straightforward meaning of lost is so obvious. (BTW - did you really mean to write *Neither OP nor me are interested...*?)

Comment: @Drew: Perhaps you hadn't noticed that OP culled his example from a writer who specialises in teaching English as a foreign language. Non-native speakers could obviously have trouble understanding why *losing* doesn't work the same as, say, *trailing* in the example (it's a *semantic* issue, not a matter of grammar *per se*). And yes - I did mean to write *Neither OP nor me...* there. I'm quite well aware some people would object to it - but that's their problem, not mine. I have full confidence in my own command of English, irrespective of the pedantic position.